# query not generating the desired xml output

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to generate the following xml but it isn't getting generated as desired:

```
<partyIds>
   <id>2222</id>
   <id>2222</id>
   <id>2222</id>
</partyIds>
```

The xml generated by my query is as follows:

```
<partyIds>
   <companyId>105612</companyId>
</partyIds>
<partyIds>
   <companyId>106079</companyId>
</partyIds>
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT top 1000 (mc.companyId)
FROM ciqMarketCap mc 
JOIN ciqCompany c 
       ON c.companyid = mc.companyid
WHERE c.companyStatusTypeId NOT IN (5,6) AND  c.companyTypeId IN (1,4) for xml path('partyIds')
```

Comment: mysql OR sql-server?

Comment: share table schema and sample input

Comment: The desired xml input is mentioned in my post which is the first line.

Comment: The query as shown in the post is querying companyid which is an int field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can combine column aliases with `for xml` attributes:

```
select top (3) ao.object_id as [id]
from sys.all_objects ao
for xml path(''), type, root('partyIds');
```

Alternatively, this syntax would also work:

```
select top (3) ao.object_id as [node()]
from sys.all_objects ao
for xml path('id'), type, root('partyIds');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define root.

> for xml path(''), root ('partyIds')

Comment: This is close to what I need but it is generating <partyIds><companyid>12323</companyid> . I need ids instead of companyid.Also when I copying the result its look like its getting truncated.Not able to copy the entire results

Comment: companyId is your column name, you can use alias to change that.
**SELECT DISTINCT top 1000 mc.companyId as id**

Comment: Try using `as` keyword- SELECT DISTINCT top 1000 (mc.companyId) as id ....